# Create API to add Components

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to create an `API` to modify a `Scene`.

For sample, the default `fxml` had following `Components`:

[image: Default View]

With an `API`, i wan't to add some `Components` under the **Connection Name:**, for sample:

[image: Wanted]

First, i had created an `Controller` for the `FXML`:

> <BorderPane fx:controller="ConnectionController" [...]

and add an `ID` to the `GridPane`, that i wan't to modify:

> <GridPane fx:id="form" [...]

On `Controller`'s side, i had register the `Component` to speak with it:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class ConnectionController extends Controller {
    @FXML GridPane form;

    public void init(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public GridPane getForm() {
        return form;
    }
}
```

But when i try to get the `Controller` from the `FXML` to get the `GridPane` for adding some `Components`, nothing will be applied, for Sample:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/ui/" + file + ".fxml"));
Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
theController = fxmlLoader.getController(); // <<<< Here i get the Controller
[...] // Set the Stage, add to Scene and show the Stage...
```

On the Plugin's side:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setText("click me!");
theController.getForm().add(button, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Can you tell me, what's wrong? I had not really experience with `JavaFX` - On "older Java techniques" with `AWT`/`Swing` components, i know, you must **invalidate** or **repaint* the components... It's here the same possibility?

**EDIT:**

When i get the `GridPane` with `getForm()` method, i can change the style properties like:

```
theController.getForm().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF0000");
```

[image]

But when i set the `Background Color` to `red`, add the `Button` and set after that the `Background Color` to `green` for example, the background will be not painted green:

```
theController.getForm().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF0000");
theController.getForm().add(button, 1, 1, 0, 0);
theController.getForm().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #0000FF");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is strange:

```
theController.getForm().add(button, 1, 1, 0, 0).
```

The `GridPane` API being called is:

> [add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-int-int-).

So you are asking the node to span `0` rows and columns, which isn't really possible.

When you try to run this code on Java 8u144, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rowSpan must be greater or equal to 1, but was 0.
```

My guess is that you are just swallowing the exception somewhere.  That would explain why code after the add statement does not appear to execute (because the thrown exception changed the flow of control).

Comment: The API Method of `add(Node, int, int, int int)` will blocking the application - I don't know why. Thats, why the background will not update after change. I have already found a solution by testing: `form.getChildren().add(component);`, `GridPane.setConstraints(component, columnIndex, rowIndex);`. Curiously, Java gives me **no exceptions**, i had try to fetch it with an Exception-Block with `try/catch`.

Comment: Probably, [`gridPane.add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-) would work as well, you don't need to set any rowspan or colspan values if you are not trying to span multiple rows and columns (which I don't think you really mean to do here).